# "A component named dlgPrinterSettings Already exists."

Tags: delphi

Every now and then I sometime get the following error "A component named dlgPrinterSettings Already exists." not necesarry the "dlgprintersettings" everytime, but still, I would like to know what might be the cause of this error in the following piece of code:

```
procedure TfrmApplicationMain.actPrinterExecute(Sender: TObject);
begin
  with TdlgPrinterSettings.Create(self) do
  try
    ChkEncodeMag.IsChecked := GetUserDataBoolean('MAGNETIC_ENCODING');
    ChkEncodeFromDatabase.IsChecked := GetUserDataBoolean('MAGNETIC_DATABASE');

    ShowModal;
  finally
    SetUserData('MAGNETIC_ENCODING',BoolToStr(ChkEncodeMag.IsChecked));
    SetUserData('MAGNETIC_DATABASE',BoolToStr(ChkEncodeFromDatabase.IsChecked));
    free;
  end;
end;
```

should I use "nil" instead of "self" in the create ?

Comment: Does TdlgPrinterSettings set its name to 'dlgPrinterSettings' in its contructor?

Comment: does `Create(nil)` instead of `Create(Self)` make a difference?

Comment: I read about the nil the minute before I post this question, so I will take a try on this one

Comment: @ulrich, there is no name clash in this, TDLGprintersetting's .name property is blank when I create my dialogs this way, I never get the error myself.. but this was an enduser who got it, and sometimes pretty hard to recreate the steps when the end user quite often has theire own way to click stuff, and use the gui differently that ex. programmers testing does not :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just an observation,

if one of the `SetUserData` methods throws an exception, your TdlgPrinterSettings instance will not get freed. The next time you call `actPrinterExecute`would give you the error you mention.

---

ps. Don't use `with`. Declare a local variable and use that. You can search on *with & Delphi* to find some heated debates about it's use. I'm not guilt-free myself here but I would not use it in *this* case.

Comment: perhaps i should dig into the setuserdata, but eventually in the try finally it allways frees up the form even tho there was fired an exception within..

Comment: mostly I just use with if I am 100% sure it will not conflict or confuse with other objects. I mostly do it for readability purposes since imo large chunks of code with i.e. label1.caption := 'blbalba'; label1.left := 100; label1.top := 100; etc etc, but you know what I mean:)

Comment: If you haven't done so already, I recommend using madExcept or Eurekalog and try to work from there.

Comment: -1. Does not answer the question. Please do the nit-picking in a comment, not an answer.

Comment: What nit-picking do you refer to? Usage of with? I'm not going to argue about your statement that it isn't an answer, I know you know your stuff, but you might explain *why* the observation is wrong because I for one don't have a clue.

Answer (score -1):

I suppose that :

There is an Component on your Form named " dlgPrinterSettings " , it`s Class Name will be " TdlgPrinterSettings "
When you Create an Component by this line :

**with TdlgPrinterSettings.Create(self) do**

A Component will create that derived from " TdlgPrinterSettings " , and it`s name is equal to your default component that you put on the form , So you will get an Error !

why you want to create it ?

If " TdlgPrinterSettings " is a " TPrinterSetupDialog " you do like this :

```
procedure TfrmApplicationMain.actPrinterExecute(Sender: TObject);
begin
 with TPrinterSetupDialog.Create(self) do
  try
   ChkEncodeMag.IsChecked := GetUserDataBoolean('MAGNETIC_ENCODING');
   ChkEncodeFromDatabase.IsChecked := GetUserDataBoolean('MAGNETIC_DATABASE');

   ShowModal;
  finally
   SetUserData('MAGNETIC_ENCODING',BoolToStr(ChkEncodeMag.IsChecked));
   SetUserData('MAGNETIC_DATABASE',BoolToStr(ChkEncodeFromDatabase.IsChecked));
   free;
  end;
end;
```

I`m not sure but maybe it is !!

Good Luck ...

Comment: -1 When creating a component at runtime its Name is empty. So there will be no name clash. I think Ulrich Gerhardt is on the right track.